# MOSFET Drivers to decrease turn on/off times

Tags: mosfet, delay, mosfet-driver

Using MOSFET drivers, can one decrease the turn on/turn off time of MOSFETs than indicated in their datasheet.

If so, by how much? Is it in the scale of orders or just barely?

Comment: No​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 8):

No.  The datasheet tells you what the bare part can do, already assuming very fast gate transistions.  The test conditions are usually listed in the datasheet.  Read it.